# Django oscar product description

Tags: django, django-oscar

I am exploring django oscar ecommerce and I wanted to find out if there was a way to insert images into product description.

Under dashboard, it doesn't allow me to insert images or edit it in html mode.

[image]
Many Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible - you can swap out the default editor for your own that allows embedding images - e.g., with django-ckeditor.

Comment: amazing! thank you.